# How to get a Scrolling Activity With Navigation Drawer in Android (Material Design)

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I've been interested in material design and wanted to build a layout for the main page of my app so that it looks like the default template for Scrolling Activity but also has a Navigation Drawer like the default template for Navigation Drawer Activity for easy navigation.

As an example, Google's Play Music app already does this sort of thing.
Have a look:

[Scrolling list with a banner and a FAB at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se903.jpg),

[Navigation Drawer, accessed by swiping from over to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qjS1.jpg)

I've searched everywhere and could find a direct way for implementing such a layout. So I tried doing it on my own and with some changes here and there in the default templates of Scrolling Activity and the Navigation Drawer Activity I was able to achieve something along those lines but not exactly what I was looking for.

I was hopping if someone could present a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got exactly what I wanted, you simply need to include Scrolling Activity's layout inside the layout of Navigation Drawer Activity and it works nicely.

You can use the default templates for these activities given in the Android Studio to save yourself some time or start from scratch.

Let me know if anyone needs some code and I will be more than happy to post it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the DrawerLayout supplied in the Android support library with a FrameLayout and ListView to achieve the Navigation drawer. In the FrameLayout, you will display a Fragment which takes a ScrollView to display scrollable content. The Fragment can also have other widgets that let you customize your layout.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to android and wasn't able to understand fully what you're trying to say. Is there an example that I may be able to take a look at?

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NavDrawer - The examples are from the excellent book "A Busy Coder's guide to Android Development" by Mark Murphy. The book goes a long way in helping to learn Android. You can also go up one level and see other examples.