# A Navigation Drawer activity with a nested tab swing activity on android

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have read some posts, where people successfully experiment with nested activities of other kind. So in principle this should be possible.

This is how I imagine my nested activity:
The main user activity is with navigation Drawer on the left.
After touching one of the drawer options, a 'nested activity' with swipe tabs would display, within its parent (main user) activity and thus the navigation drawer available on the left.

See example:
[image: A drawer activity]
Fig 1. A Navigation drawer activity

[image: A swipe tabs activity]
Fig 2: A swipe tabs activity

And I want a combination of them like this:
[image: A navi-drawer activity with swipe tab activity inside.]
Fig 3. A navi-drawer activity with swipe tab activity inside.

So I want both. Navigation drawer as mother and a tab-swipe activity inside (say under one of the drawer options.)

Such combination seems a bit more complex and unusual, so I wonder whether there are any limitations there with. 
Especially with older android releases.

Therefore my Q: Does anyone have deeper experiences with this ?
Are there any particular issues connected with my intention ? Will this combination limit my app to newer android releases only ?

And lastly, is there any good example ?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036869/how-to-get-a-scrolling-activity-with-navigation-drawer-in-android-material-desi), which goes similar way as I, but the only answer available is not quite what I want.

Comment: You might wish to define what a "nested" activity means.

Comment: My nested activity: 
The main user activity is with Navigation Drawer on the left.
After touching one of the drawer options, a 'nested activity' with swipe tabs would display, within its parent (main user) activity and thus the navigation drawer available on the left.

Comment: Having activities inside of activities has been deprecated as a technique for over five years, and it was a fairly poor idea even before then. As Anton suggests in an answer, use fragments or some other approach.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thanks for reply. That is what I thought. It looks like I will follow the suggestion given in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036869/how-to-get-a-scrolling-activity-with-navigation-drawer-in-android-material-desi

Answer (score 1):

You should use fragments. So your main activity have FrameLayout as a container and when you click on drawer items you just replace fragments in container.
Take a look at these samples:

- [First](http://joerichard.net/android/android-how-to-change-fragments-when-navigation-drawer-item-selected/)
- [Second](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)

Comment: Thanx, I already have established an activity with navigation drawer :)
But as I tried to explain further, I seek to add a tab - swipe option inside.

Comment: @Peter Create fragment with tab layout  and view pager inside it

Comment: Hmm, sounds smart - looks like this idea I needed to avoid nested activities, which CommonsWare told was deprecated technique for ages. In fact I started with fragments, but as new to Android I did not know how to make them swipe with contents :)

Comment: @Peter these samples will help you ;)